# Give Pointer from Library

Tags: c, pointers, static-libraries

Ii've a big Problem. I write a static Library, what I would like to use in a Software. My Problem is: if you give a pointer from a function out of the library back to the main program the pointer have not the value from the pointer in the Library. Is there an issue, if you give pointer from an Libay.a back to the main.c

Main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

char *ptr;
Prallow_its(ptr, 122);
printf("%s", ptr);
return 0;

}
```

Prallow.c from Prallow.a

```
[...]

char *Prallow_its(char *ptr, int i){
static char buffer[255];
sprintf(buffer, "%u", i);
ptr = buffer;
return ptr;
}

[...]
```

Comment: Are you using C or C++? Tag just one.

Comment: Also, your question makes no sense.

Comment: C passes by value, so the line `ptr = buffer` in the function does **not** change the value of `ptr` in `main`.

Comment: @SandiMilicevic that's not true due to the `static` keyword.

Comment: @SandiMilicevic Incorrect, the `static` keyword gives the buffer a different storage class, it behaves more or less like a global (except that, of course, you can't access it from the outside). So returning it is perfectly valid.

Comment: `int test(int i) {static int j = 5; i = j; return i;} int main() {int x = 1; test(x); printf("%d\n", x);}` should print 5 right? Since `j` is `static`?

Comment: @immibis No, since C passes function arguments by value. `x` is passed by value to `test`, therefore the variable `x` inside `main` is not modified at all by `test` and will still be 1.

Comment: @gurka It was a rhetorical question.

Comment: @NikePrallow As a response to your answer (that probably will be removed since it should be a comment). It works here: http://ideone.com/FF7BG0

Comment: @immibis Ah. It was unclear, but I understand now that the question was asked to the person whose comments are deleted. :)

Comment: @gurka It works only if you have the function in the same file as the call. If the function is in the Library and the Call in the main.c then it doesn't [work.i.stack.imgur.com/eHFkC.png]

Comment: @NikePrallow Works for me with different files: http://pastebin.com/yS2Nemqa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine to return the pointer to your static buffer from the library.  It lives in the same address space as the rest of your program.  Of course, it's not thread-safe but that's a separate issue.

The real problem is the way you are calling it:

```
char *ptr;               // <-- ptr uninitialised
Prallow_its(ptr, 122);   // <-- return value ignored
printf("%c", ptr);       // <-- ptr still uninitialised
```

You should instead do this:

```
ptr = Prallow_its( ptr, 122 );
```

Alternatively, you *could* allow `ptr` to be modified by `Prallow_its`.  In that case, it must be defined like this:

```
char *Prallow_its( char **ptr, int i )
{
    static char buffer[255];
    sprintf(buffer, "%u", i);
    *ptr = buffer;
    return *ptr;
}
```

And called like this:

```
Prallow_its( &ptr, 122 );
```

Comment: Or, since the function does not use the passed-in value of argument `ptr`, you might just as well do this: `ptr = Prallow_its( NULL, 122 );` (with the OP's implementation).

Answer (score 0):

C passes by value, so the line `ptr = buffer` in the library function does **not** change the value of `ptr` in `main`.

Also, the library function doesn't do anything with the pointer that's passed in, so there's no reason to pass the pointer. The code in Main.c should be

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{
    char *ptr = Prallow_its(122);
    printf("%s", ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

and the code in Prallow.c should be

```
char *Prallow_its(int i)
{
    static char buffer[255];
    sprintf(buffer, "%u", i);
    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: Also one can argue that the return type of `Prallow_its` should be `const char*`... But that's just my opinion :)

Comment: @gurka Yup, you probably don't want to the caller to be messing with the buffer. OTOH, if it was my library, I wouldn't use a static buffer at all.  The library should either `malloc` the buffer, or force the caller to pass in a buffer (along with the size of the buffer).